# Bug in Area 51 example question deletion and undeletion

Tags: bug, area-51, deleted-questions

I decided to delete one of my example questions on Area 51 since I poorly phrased it and thus received a few downvotes. The question wouldn't be useful either as off-topic example.

What happened:

- I deleted the example question, having score -2.
- Shortly after, I tought it would be good to leave a comment why I
  deleted the question in case one could see it.
- I undeleted the question.
- I noticed the question had score 0.

That isn't good, is it?

But it gets even more buggy, because my reputation was never restored. I don't really care about the 4 points, but it is weird since on other sites your reputation is restored after deleting a question or answer.

Comment: Dunno about score, but reputation on Area51 is never recalculated automatically, even after years. There are millions of "zombie" points there, that recalc will nuke. To recalculate your rep, go to http://area51.stackexchange.com/reputation and click "Trigger Reputation Recalc" button in the bottom. ***(WARNING: you might lose major part of your reputation as result)***

Comment: @ShadowWizard I triggered rep recalc and gained 4 reputation. Still, deleting and undeleting shouldn't reset score.